# Delete from current line to last line visible on screen

Tags: vim

Is there an command like `dG` (will delete from the current line to the end of file) which will delete from current line to including last line visible on screen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes there is.

```
dL
```

does it.

You may want to check the motions: `M, L, H` (e.g. `:h L`)